# Interrupt 09 handling in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I have been trying to write my own handling for int 09 to be used as a multiplayer game in the future ,So I am testing it first but actually nothing is being stored in the array KeyList I am using.

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h

.DATA
msg       db "Ii",'$'
KeyList db 128 dup (0)



.CODE

main proc far
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

; enter graphic mode
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h

; get the address of the existing int09h handler
    mov ax, 3509h ; Get Interrupt Vector
    int  21h ; -> ES:BX
    push es bx
    cli
; replace the existing int09h handler with ours
    mov dx, offset onKeyEvent
    mov ax, 2509h
    int 21h
    sti
    mov cx,20
    ll: mov dx,1
        cmp [KeyList+48h],1
        je print
        loop ll
    jmp exitt
    print: mov dx, offset msg
           mov ah,9
           int 21h
           cmp cx,0
           jnz ll
    exitt:pop dx
    pop ds
    mov ax, 2509h
    int 21h

;;;;;;;;;;
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp         
onKeyEvent proc   ; custom handler for int 09h
    push ax 
    push bx
    in   al, 60h
    mov  ah, 0
    mov  bx, ax
    and  bx, 127           ; 7-bit scancode goes to BX
    shl  ax, 1             ; 1-bit pressed/released goes to AH
    xor  ah, 1             ; -> AH=1 Pressed, AH=0 Released
    mov  KeyList + [bx], ah
    mov  al, 20h           ; The non specific EOI (End Of Interrupt)
    out  20h, al
    pop  bx
    pop ax
    iret
onKeyEvent endp 

;--------------------------------;
end main
```

I am testing the input in a loop and try to press the up key but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to insert some timing or sleeping in your loop, as is it will end almost immediately and it won't detect any keys pressed. (Even if you didn't make any other errors, which I didn't check exhaustively.)

Comment: `int 21,25` sets the interrupt vector to `ds:dx`. But your `ds` points to the data segment, not the code segment.

Comment: Other than that `jnz ll` will always jump. And you should push/set/pop `ds` within your interrupt handler to insure it points to the expected data. And in graphics mode 13h your interrupt 21h function 09h string may or may not show up legibly.

Comment: but the assembler refuses to put my interrupt handler in the data segment.

Comment: @zizo You can set the `ds` register to the correct (code) segment then for the interrupt 21h function 2509h call. Don't forget to set it back to your data segment afterwards.

Comment: I have tried the code and it is working but the first press is always neglected in this case, Do you guys have an answer for this ?+ Is the input buffer empty after the new interrupt handler, I mean, Can I use int 16h/0h ?

Comment: You should mention the assembler that you're using: MASM, TASM, ...

Answer (score 2):

Using the .EXE program format is probably not what you should do while still learning to code in assembly. The example code upon which your current program is based was using the .COM program format for a reason. The 4 segment registers start all equal to each other and that's already a big plus.

Both @ecm and @interjay already explained what was wrong. The only thing still missing is a working example:

```
    ORG  256               ; .COM file begin with CS=DS=ES=SS

; enter graphic mode
    mov  ax, 13h
    int  10h
; -------------------------
    mov  ax, 3509h         ; Get Interrupt Vector
    int  21h               ; -> ES:BX
    push es                ; (1)
    push bx                ; (2)
; replace the existing int09h handler with ours
    mov  dx, onKeyEvent
    mov  ax, 2509h
    int  21h
; -------------------------
mainLoop:
    cmp  byte [KeyList+01h], 1 ; ESC
    je   done

    mov  dx, msg2
    cmp  byte [KeyList+48h], 0 ; UP
    je   print
    mov  dx, msg1
    cmp  byte [KeyList+48h], 1 ; UP
    je   print

    jmp  mainLoop
; -------------------------
print:
    mov  ah, 09h
    int  21h
    mov  cx, 18            ; 1 second
    call waitTicks
    jmp  mainLoop
; -------------------------
done:
    pop  dx                ; (2)
    pop  ds                ; (1)
    mov  ax, 2509h
    int  21h
    mov  ax, 0003h
    int  10h
    mov  ax, 4C00h
    int  21h
; -------------------------
onKeyEvent:                ; custom handler for int 09h
    push ax 
    push bx
    in   al, 60h
    mov  ah, 0
    mov  bx, ax
    and  bx, 127           ; 7-bit scancode goes to BX
    shl  ax, 1             ; 1-bit pressed/released goes to AH
    xor  ah, 1             ; -> AH=1 Pressed, AH=0 Released
    mov  [cs:KeyList+bx], ah
    mov  al, 20h           ; The non specific EOI (End Of Interrupt)
    out  20h, al
    pop  bx
    pop  ax
    iret
; -------------------------
; IN (cx) OUT (cx=0)
waitTicks:
    push ds
    push ax
    xor  ax, ax
    mov  ds, ax
.a: mov  ax, [046Ch]
.b: cmp  ax, [046Ch]
    je   .b
    loop .a
    pop  ax
    pop  ds
    ret
; -------------------------
msg1:     db "[Up is pressed]", 13, 10, "$"
msg2:     db "[Up is released]", 13, 10, "$"
KeyList:  db 128 dup (0)
```

> ```
> mov  [cs:KeyList+bx], ah
> ```

Because in this .COM program the KeyList lives in the code segment, a mere CS: segment override prefix is needed to keep this handler correct for situations where the DS segment register could be pointing elsewhere.

The program pauses 1 second each time a message is printed. Once *your* program does something more useful, you should experiment with this delay, and probably even look for a delay with a sub-tick granularity.

> Is the input buffer empty after the new interrupt handler, I mean, Can I use int 16h/0h ?

The new interrupt handler comes instead of the old one. There is nothing in it that stores to the normal BIOS keystroke buffer, so don't expect `int 16h` to return anything useful.

Comment: The above code uses FASM syntax.

Comment: Good work, however two comments on the wait ticks function: 1. It can help to reduce CPU time if you idle; in Real/Virtual 86 Mode DOS you can either `sti` \ `hlt` or call interrupt 2Fh function 1680h. 2. If you do idle, between two accesses to the tick value low word more than one tick may have passed. This bit me on a physical machine when running FDAPM. I adjusted my timers with some glue that lets them count down more than one tick per iteration: https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/0ca824e8fe80/source/ss.asm#l67 + midnight handling in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/insight/rev/1c86495bcd6d