# Sleep Function in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I have making a multiplayer game and implemented my own interrupt to handle multiplayer input but there is a problem that whenever I execute a function for sleeping or wait time the program crashes, This is the last procedure that crashed the program

```
my_delay proc 
push ax 
; Input: CX = delay count
    ; Output: None
    ; Description: Pauses execution for approximately CX * 55 ms
    mov cx,delay
    mov al,0
    mov ah, 86h     ; INT 21h, Function 86h - "wait" or "sleep"
    int 21h
    pop ax
  ret 
my_delay endp
```

Comment: I have also tried int 15h/86h and still same results, Can this be caused by the new interrupt?

Comment: Are you under DOS? Is maybe some other code depending on register values? What does "crashed" mean?

Comment: [INT 21h/AH=86h](https://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-3250.htm) is **not** a function *" *wait" or "sleep"* in DOS. Use `AH=89h` instead.

Comment: What does "implemented my own interrupt" mean? Do you call DOS service function from interrupt handler?

Comment: @dimich I mean defined a new interrupt handler

Comment: @zizo Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe what exactly "crashed the program" mean. There are too many possible reasons for "crash" to guess.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ; Input: CX = delay count
> mov cx,delay
> ```

Loading CX straight from the *delay* variable itself doesn't go well with the comment about CX being an argument to the proc.

> ```
> ; Description: Pauses execution for approximately CX * 55 ms
> ```

CX expresses a multiple of about **6**5 ms.

> ```
> mov al,0
> ```

This function does not depend on AL, but DX, you should have initialized. The number of microseconds is expected in the combo CX:DX.

> ```
> int 21h
> ```

The function does not belong to the DOS api. It is a sysyem BIOS function that belongs to `int 15h`.

---

Are you running your program in DOSBox? If you do, then know that DOSBox is buggy with this particular function. See [Nate Eldredge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194265/dosbox-is-buggy-with-int-15h-ah-86h/66845163?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C29.9484#66845163) on the matter.

```
print:
    mov  ah, 09h
    int  21h
;;;    mov  cx, 18            ; 1 second
;;;    call waitTicks
    mov  cx, 15           ; 1 second == 1000000 µsec
    mov  dx, 16960
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    jmp  mainLoop
```

I modified the code in my answer to your previous question [Interrupt 09 handling in assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608007/interrupt-09-handling-in-assembly-x86/77615783#77615783) and it worked fine ... today! In the past this wasn't always true. See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101035/a-low-tech-approach-to-measuring-game-speed that uses an alternative approach for (very) short delays.

Another work-around is to *never invoke this BIOS function with CX non-zero*:

```
; IN (cx:dx) OUT () MOD (ax,cx)
MicroWait:
    jcxz .b
    push dx
    mov  dx, 65535
.a: push cx
    xor  cx, cx
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    pop  cx
    loop .a
    pop  dx
.b: mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    ret
; ----------------------
```